# Is there a better way to optimize this SQL query?

Tags: sql

Assume my table has millions of records.

The following columns have indexes:

- type
- date
- unique_id

Here is my query:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) T.TIME, T.TYPE, F.NAME,
B.NAME, T.MESSAGE
FROM MY_TABLE T
LEFT OUTER JOIN FOO F ON F.ID = T.FID
LEFT OUTER JOIN BAR B ON B.ID = T.BID
WHERE T.TYPE IN ('success', 'failure')
AND T.DATE BETWEEN 1592585183437 AND 1594232320525
AND T.UNIQUE_ID = "my unique ID"
ORDER BY T.DATE DESC
```

My question is am I causing myself any trouble with this query if I have tons of records in my table? Can this be optimized further?

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry about that, updated

Comment: There are three individual indexes or some composite one(s)?

Comment: Some things to try - rewrite the query - Sometimes flipping the order of the joins helps dramatically.  Indexes - this can make a night and day difference, especially with large amounts of data.  Grabbing fewer records - Even 1000 is still a reasonably large chunk.  Do you really need 1000?  Can you get away with 100, or even fewer?  The less data you're grabbing from the db, the better it will perform.  Last but certainly not least - try running through SQL profiler if you have access.  This can identify bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is am I causing myself any trouble with this query if I have tons of records
> in my table?

Wrong question. As long as you are only asking for data you need, you NEED it. Any trouble means you STIL need it.

The query looks as good as it gets. I somehow doubt the TOP 10000 (that is a LOT of data unless you compress it somehow).

The question is more whether you have the proper indices. Without the proper indices. I would also not use strings like this for TYPE, but then the question is about the query, not possible failures in table design.

Check indices.